# how to append the .trx file generated while executing dotnet test command

Tags: .net-core

Per my requirement, I have test case id stored in a list and I am iterating over this list to execute the testcases

```
for (int i=0;i<=list.size();i++){
dotnet test project.dll --filter Category=list[i] --logger trx;logfilename=testResults[i].trx
}
```

**What is actually happening** is we are generating .trx file for each case

because

```
for (int i=0;i<=list.size();i++){
dotnet test project.dll --filter Category=list[i] --logger "trx;logfilename=testResults.trx
}
```

is not working as I need

**What is Expected** some how if we can have a  single file for whole execution which have the result for each test from the list